# mod_expires enabled and cache flush

Tags: 7, .htaccess

I my apache I have mod_expires enabled. My htaccess contains:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  # Enable expirations.
  ExpiresActive On
  # Cache all files for 2 weeks after access (A).
  ExpiresDefault A1209600
```

Problem: If I make html change, it is not visible even after flushing all caches in drupal.
Question: Is it possible to setup html expiring to say 1 hour and other things like css/scripts/images to say 1 day?
Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

If you use boost module "flushing all caches" maybe not work. Go admin > configuration and open boost configuration, there a tab named "cache expiration" then undo click "Ignore a cache flush command if cron issued the request." I think this usable for you

Comment: I am not using boost module